# CDK: how to specify a private subnet for launch template?

Tags: aws-cdk

When creating a Launch Template with CDK, in Python, how do you specify the subnet, which you can from the web console.

I know that it is not possible using a L2 contruct as per this github issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14494

But I cannot find the way to specify the subnet in the [examples and documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/CfnLaunchTemplate.html) of the L1 contruct.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses the L2 constructs. The subnets are selected for the ASG, not the launch template. I select the subnets using tags.

https://github.com/patrickmryan/cdk-asg/blob/main/asg/asg_stack.py#L113-L142

Comment: But I want to create a LaunchTemplate, not AutoScalingGroup ....